# Serve smaller images in ACF image loop

Tags: php, wordpress, image, advanced-custom-fields

I have a product overview page with 1 image per product:
https://axces.be/nl/product/

You can add multiple images to a products. All these images are shown on the detail page. But on the product page, you only see the first image.

My template looks like this:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="single-prod">

    <div class="single-prod__image">
        <?php
            $productImages = get_field('product_images');
        ?>

        <img src="<?php echo $productImages[0]['product_image']?>" />
    </div>
</a>
```

But now the images are served on the size they are uploaded. This causes a slower load time. So I want to serve smaller images.

I've tried to add the image size thumbnail to it, in order to see if the load time is better. But that doesn't work:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="single-prod">

    <div class="single-prod__image">
        <?php
            $image_size = 'thumbnail';
            $productImages = get_field('product_images');
        ?>

        <img src="<?php echo $productImages[0]['product_image']['sizes'][$image_size]; ?>" />
    </div>

    <div class="single-prod__information">
        <span class="single-prod__name">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </span>

        <span class="single-prod__short">
            <?php the_field('product_short'); ?>
        </span>
    </div>
</a>
```

So eventually, I want to achieve that the images are smaller. Not necessary the to see the thumbnail because that's probably going to crop the image.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _“But that doesn't work:”_  - and that means what exactly? Do you get PHP errors, do the images not load (and if so, have you checked the created HTML to verify the output makes sense), …?

Comment: I would recommend that you just get the post id of the media item from your ACF field, and then use that with `wp_get_attachment_image` to output the image.

Comment: Okay, I've changed the output of ACF to image ID. And to show the image, I'm using this: <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($productImages[0]['product_image']); ?>

This shows the thumbnail. So the images are cropped. They have to have to same height and width auto.

Comment: `thumbnail` is the default value for the image size parameter of wp_get_attachment_image - specify a different one then …

Comment: Thanks for your help!
This is my code right now: <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($productImages[0]['product_image'], 'small'); ?>

But still I'm not really sure if the small image is served. Also GTmetrix says that still have to serve scaled images.

It's already implemented on the live website: https://axces.be/nl/product/

Comment: _“But still I'm not really sure if the small image is served”_ - then check what image was actually requested, using your browser dev tools, network panel.